# How can I apply text highlight with VBA when writing out to a .doc file?

Tags: vba, file

I'm creating a file and writing out to it:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.CreateTextFile(tRFPath, True)
ts.WriteLine("SomeHeader" & " " & tSomeValue)
```

Is there a way I can use maybe the color constants to highlight "SomeHeader" to Yellow?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Plain text is just that. There is no formatting in a plain text file that lets you specify color/font/size. However, if you are displaying the text in a Bash shell or have configured your windows command console correctly, you could use ANSI Escape Codes to format the text.